# nodejs - how to manage multiple files upload in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I'm writing a simple nodejs app that I want to pack using [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg). The app will give to the user the ability to upload some files that after are processed from the embedded server script will be sended back to the vue client app.As I know, I need to add `multipart/form-data` to the vuejs form?Since I'm new to express, what's the best way to handle multiple files upload?Since pkg will pack the app to work with a virtual filesystem, how I can create a temp dir in the folder where the app is executed when the files are uploaded?I've seen the [provided example](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js) on the express website but it uses some dependencies and I don't want to have too many libraries for my project.

This is the basic code I have at the moment

```js
const http = require('http'); 
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

class eCrypt {
    constructor(){
        this.app = app;
        this.assets = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'assets/'})
    }

    async init(){
        this.app.use(express.static())
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({
            extended: true
        }));

        this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile('index.html', {root: this.assets});
        });

        this.app.post('/compressEncrypt', (req, res) => {
            //here I need to manage uploaded files
        }); 

    }
    
    async encryptAndCompress(data){
      //in this method I'm processing the files
    }

}
```

Comment: Honestly I'd recommend taking a look at multer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Yes it's a dependency but installing express already adds hundreds of them so I don't think a few more will kill it.

Comment: @GregoireLodi I've solved by installing [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload#readme) that will handle under the hood all the uploaded files